# Creating monthly report

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm creating a monthly report and I have a table:

```
DriverName    TodayDate     WeekNo    KM
----------    ----------    ------    ---
ALI           02-01-2018    1         2
ALI           04-01-2018    1         4
ALI           08-01-2018    2         3
ALI           09-01-2018    2         8
AHMED         05-02-2018    1         9
AHMED         05-02-2018    1         9
...
So on
```

And I'm trying the results like:

```
DriverName    KM/W1  KM/W2  KM/W3  KM/W4  KM/W5   Total
----------    -----  -----  -----  -----  -----   -----
ALI           6      11     0      0      0       17
AHMED         18     0      0      0      0       18
```

I have tried but don't know how should I write inner select query:

```
Select DriverName,(Select KM FROM Traveling Where WeekNo=1) as KM/W1, ... Where Traveling
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
SELECT drivername, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN weekno = 1 THEN km 
             ELSE 0 
           END) AS wk1km, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN weekno = 2 THEN km 
             ELSE 0 
           END) AS wk2km, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN weekno = 3 THEN km 
             ELSE 0 
           END) AS wk3km, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN weekno = 4 THEN km 
             ELSE 0 
           END) AS wk4km, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN weekno = 5 THEN km 
             ELSE 0 
           END) AS wk5km, 
       Sum(km)  AS total 
FROM   (SELECT drivername, 
               weekno, 
               Sum(km) km 
        FROM   traveling 
        GROUP  BY drivername, 
                  weekno) AS t 
GROUP  BY drivername 
ORDER  BY total;
```

Here is sample [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/dd15fa/5) to test.

Snapshot of *demo* run:
[image]

Comment: it will show 0 where there is no data. I just updated the post with the demo run snapshot. If you can fiddle your data, I can double check if results are different.

Comment: I don't understand when you are saying its not working. Please provide details, what is not working. I used your data exactly, and the expected & actual result is matching. I updated the post tallying exactly your data & expected result.